# static variable and pointer to static variables in c/c++

Tags: c, pointers, static, storage-class-specifier

If i have static variable:

```
static int a;
```

And I want a pointer to point to this variable, should the pointer look like:

```
static int* f;
f=&a;
```

And if I return this f to a function call with an assignment statement to a pointer of type static int* will this variable be accessible in that function?

Also:

```
int a;
static int* f;
f=&a; // does this mean now a is a static variable and it will be retained until the program ends?
static int b;
int* c;
c=&n; // is this possible?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;
static int* f;
f=&a; // does this mean now a is a static variable and it will be retained until the program ends?
```

> "[D]oes this mean now a is a static variable"?

No it does not. The `static` property only apply to the variable you explicitly define as `static`. In the example above only `f` is `static`. The life-time of `a` will end when its surrounding scope ends, making any pointer to it invalid at that point.

```
static int b;
int* c;
c=&n; // is this possible?
```

> "[I]s this possible?"

Yes that's fine. The life-time of local static variables are the full life-time of the program. And global variables (static or not) also have a life-time of the full program. That means pointers to them will always stay valid.

[This storage-class specifier reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) might be helpful to read through.